# How to color the background of nebular card in angular nebular

Tags: angular, typescript

> Can't color the background in nebular card in angular.

Comment: Add some of your code samples here.

Answer (score 0):

visit this link and select (theme) from top right:
[link](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/card/theme#nbcardcomponent)

```
card-background-color   background-basic-color-1    #ffffff 
card-text-color         text-basic-color            #222b45
```